# Is there a name for a language feature that allows assignment/creation?

Tags: javascript, language-features, object-notation

This is a bit hard for me to articulate, but in PHP you can say something like:

`$myArray['someindex'] = "my string";`

and if there is no index named that, it will create/assign the value, and if there IS an index, it will overwrite the existing value.

Compare this to Javascript where today I had to do checks like so:

`if (!myObject[key]) myObject[key] = "value";`

I know this may be a bit of a picky point, but is there a name for the ability of PHP (and many other languages) to do these checks on their own as opposed to the more verbose (read: PITA) method of Javascript?

**EDIT**

I confused myself in asking this. Let's say you want to add to this structure:

```
myobject = {
    holidays : {easter : {date : 4/20/2010,
                          religion : Christianity}
                holi : {date : 3/10/2010,
                        religion : hindu} 
}
```

I had a problem today where I received tabular data and I wanted to put it into a tree sort of like this by building an object.

When I started my loops, I had trouble making NEW indices like `myobject['holidays'][thisVariable][date] = 4/20/2010` if the tree hadn't been mostly built to that point.

I'll grab a code sample from my other computer if this isn't clear, sorry for the poor thinking.

Comment: There was a recent question that sounds the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497278/how-can-i-declare-a-value-deep-in-an-object-tree-using-variable-properties-in-jav but no name for the feature was given

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would guess 'auto-vivification' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification from Perl might be relevant, but it works different than you described. The wiki page has a good summary. Other languages like Ruby support a "default action" hook for hash keys that have not been assigned, which can be used for auto-vivification as well.

For instance, in Ruby:

```
>> h = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = {}}
=> {}
>> h["hello"]["world"] = 20
=> 20
>> h["hello"]["world"]
=> 20
```

Comment: Beat me to mentioning *autovivification*, although I hadn't realized it referred to something so specific in Perl. I thought it was just the general concept of creating "implied" parts of a data structure.

Comment: This will only work one level deep. It can be done recursively with `h = Hash.new &block = lambda {|lambh,k| lambh[k] = Hash.new &block}`

Comment: Somehow through my obtuse example you made sense of my question AND delivered the trivia answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You are mistaken. To assign a value to an object's key in javascript, you don't need to perform that check. The value will be assigned whether there is already a value for that key or not.

Think about it. How could you ever get values into an object or hash if you had to have a value there first?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript does exactly the same thing as PHP here: myObject[key] = "value" will overwrite the existing value if one exists. Can you tell us why you think otherwise?